# get scope_id value from current store-view

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, store-view, core-config-data

How i can get the scope_id value from core_config_data table of the current store-view?. I've tried using:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

But this doesn't return the scope_id value.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need scope_id?

Comment: because i need to get the config paths from an specific scope_id (store-view), when data is saved after selecting a store-view

Comment: @Guille is this is the front end or the admin? Cause in the admin section `Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();` will always be the admin store id which is 0

Answer (score 11):

`core_config_data` table contain two important fields `scope` and `scope_id`.

There are three scope types

- default
- websites
- stores

If scope is set to `default` then `scope_id` is always 0.

If scope is set to `websites` then `scope_id` is `website_id`.

If scope is set to `stores` then `scope_id` is `store_id`(store view).

Imagine that we need to get some config value. How Magento will get the it for current store view?

Search value by priority:

- scope == `stores` and `scope_id` == store_id(store view)
- scope == `websites` and `scope_id` == website_id (to which belongs current store view)
- scope == `default`
- default section of `config.xml`

Comment: Thanks. However when i tried to retrieve the scope_id value with Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId(); i always receive "0" on frontend, but when i check the table it says 2 or 3 depending on the store-view i selected...

Comment: Do you switch between store views on frontend?

Comment: no, i need to get the current scope_id value of the selected store-view when the user press Save Config. button

Comment: scope_id is different for different config values and is not unique for the store view.

Comment: i think scope_id value is unique because when i check the sql table core_config_data directly, i can see this value changes depending on the store-view i select, eg: English = 1, German = 2 etc....

Comment: ok. For example some config value will be set for website scope and another for store view scope. In first case for example scope_id = 1 in second scope_id = 3. Both are used for current store view.

Comment: i'm sorry but that's not correct. If i select for example German store-view the scope_id value is 3, if i select French store-view the scope_id value is 2, then if i select Main Website view, the scope_id value is 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can get current scope_id value after Save Config with this:

$code = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config_data')->getStore();

$store_id = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($code)->getId();